# VBA- Inserting a Formula with Strings

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to assign this formula to a given cell

```
WS.Range(Cells(2, 1).Formula = ""=D2&"".""&E2&"".""&F2&"".""&G2&"".""&H2&"".""&I2&"".""&J2""
```

But getting this compile error: "Expected list separator or )"

I read on some other question that replacing " with "" would work but it is not working here.

My formula looks like this in a cell

```
=D2&"."&E2&"."&F2&"."&G2&"."&H2&"."&I2&"."&J2
```

Comment: First of all, `WS.Range(Cells(2, 1)` should be `WS.Cells(2, 1)`, no `Range`.

Comment: `WS.Cells(2, 1).Formula = "=D2&"".""&E2&"".""&F2&"".""&G2&"".""&H2&"".""&I2&"".""&J2"`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Big Ben and Scott! I combined your answers and it worked. I was just copy-pasting old code and made this error.